# how to limit number of rows in UITableView and then display all the rows on See All button click swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to limit number of rows in tableView say I want to show only 2 rows initially and if user clicks "See All" button then display all the rows. The data (array) for tableView is coming from CoreData. I have entered (saved) all the data in another ViewController, and fetching data on some another ViewController. There might be a case where data may be nil. Currently, I'm displaying all the rows just like --> return array.count, but I have no idea how to achieve my condition ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need a property to indicate whether you want to show all rows or not.

```
var showAllRows = false
```

In your `numberOfRowsInSection` data source method you check that value:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if showAllRows {
        return array.count
    } else {
        return min(2, array.count)
    }
}
```

Then your button handler needs to update `showAllRows` and reload the table view.

```
showAllRows = true
tableView.reloadData()
```

Comment: Nice, This answer should be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Declare a boolean variable,

> var showMoreRows = false

```
       func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            if showMoreRows {
                return array.count
            } else if array.count > 2 {
                return 2
            } else {
               return 0
        }
```

On more click trigger an event like

```
func showMoreRowsClick() {

self.showMoreRows.toggle()
self.tableView.reloadData()

}
```